# JAGS: unit-specific time trends

Tags: r, bayesian, jags

Using JAGS I am trying to estimate a model including a unit-specific time trend.
However, the problem is that I don't know how to model this and so far I have been unable to find a solution.

As an example, consider we have the following data:

```
rain<-rnorm(200)     # Explanatory variable
n1<-rnorm(200)       # Some noise
gdp<-rain+n1         # Outcome variable
ccode<-rep(1:10,20)  # Unit codes
year<-rep(1:20,10)   # Years
```

Using normal linear regression, we would estimate the model as:

```
m1<-lm(gdp~rain+factor(ccode)*year)
```

Where `factor(ccode)*year` is the unit-specific time trend. Now I want to estimate the model using JAGS. So I create parameters for the indexing:

```
N<-200
J<-max(ccode) 
T<-max(year)
```

And estimate the model,

```
library(R2jags)
library(rjags)

set.seed(42); runif(1)
dat<-list(gdp=gdp,
      rain=rain,
      ccode=ccode,
      year=year,
      N=N,J=J,T=T)

parameters<-c("b1","b0")
model.file <- "~/model.txt"
system.time(m1<-jags(data=dat,inits=NULL,parameters.to.save=parameters,
        model.file=model.file,
        n.chains=4,n.iter=500,n.burnin=125,n.thin=2))
```

with the following model file, and this is where the error is at the moment:

```
# Simple model 

model {
  # For N observations
  for(i in 1:N) {
    gdp[i] ~ dnorm(yhat[i], tau)
    yhat[i] <- b1*rain[i] + b0[ccode[i]*year[i]]   
  }

  for(t in 1:T) {
    for(j in 1:J) {
      b0[t,j] ~ dnorm(0, .01)
    }
  }
  # Priors
  b1 ~ dnorm(0, .01)   

  # Hyperpriors
  tau <- pow(sd, -2)
  sd ~ dunif(0,20)  
}
```

I am fairly sure that the way in which I define `b0` and the indexing is incorrect given the error I get when using the code: `Compilation error on line 7. Dimension mismatch taking subset of b0`. 
However, I don't know how to solve this so I wondered whether someone here has suggestions about this?

Comment: You defined `b0` as a simple vector (with just one dimension) on the `yhat` line. Later in the model, `b0` appears to be a matrix, with two dimensions. This causes the error.

Comment: Did this solve your problem?

Comment: It sounds right but so far I have been unable to correctly adjust the code. As I said, my knowledge on modelling is not great so I am still a bit stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `lm` example can also be written:

```
m1 <- lm(gdp ~ -1 + rain + factor(ccode) + factor(ccode):year)
```

The equivalent JAGS model would be:

```
M <- function() {
  for(i in 1:N) {
    gdp[i] ~ dnorm(yhat[i], sd^-2)
    yhat[i] <- b0[ccode[i]] + b1*rain[i] + b2[ccode[i]]*year[i]   
  }

  b1 ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)   
  for (j in 1:J) {
    b0[j] ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
    b2[j] ~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
  }
  sd ~ dunif(0, 100)  
}

parameters<-c('b0', 'b1', 'b2')
mj <- jags(dat, NULL, parameters, M, 3)
```

Comparing coefficients:

```
par(mfrow=c(1, 2), mar=c(5, 5, 1, 1))
plot(mj$BUGSoutput$summary[grep('^b0', row.names(mj$BUGSoutput$summary)), '50%'],
     coef(m1)[grep('^factor\\(ccode\\)\\d+$', names(coef(m1)))],
     xlab='JAGS estimate', ylab='lm estimate', pch=20, las=1,
     main='b0')
abline(0, 1)

plot(mj$BUGSoutput$summary[grep('^b2', row.names(mj$BUGSoutput$summary)), '50%'],
     coef(m1)[grep('^factor\\(ccode\\)\\d+:', names(coef(m1)))],
     xlab='JAGS estimate', ylab='lm estimate', pch=20, las=1,
     main='b2')
abline(0, 1)
```

[image]