# Matjags error: dimension mismatch

Tags: dimension

I'm new to bayesian analysis and started working with matjags. I'm trying to run a model on my movement data which is a 1x2000 array, constituting of data from 5 subjects. This is my model:

```
model {

    for ( i in 1:Ntotal ) {
        y[s[i],t] ~ dnorm( A1[s[i]] * exp( -lambda1[s[i]] ) + A2[s[i]] * exp( lambda1[s[i]]*r[s[i]] ) , sigmaY )
    }
    for ( j in Nsubj ) {
        lambda1[j] ~ dgamma( 1/10 , 1/10 )
        A1[j] ~ dgamma( 1/10 , 1/10 )
        A2[j] ~ dgamma( 1/10 , 1/10 )
        r ~ dbeta( 1 , 1 )
    }
    sigmaY ~ dgamma( 1/10 , 1/10 )
}
```

`s` is a 1x2000 array assigning the data to each subject (ie 1:400 is subject 1, 401:800 subject 2 etc..). The `exp()` functions are time constants which should describe the timecourse of learning in the data, per subject. The second timecourse is always larger than the first, so 0 < r < 1. t is my 1x2000 timevector.
Now I got following error: Dimension mismatch in subset expression of y
I first thought the problem lies in my timevector t, but when I removed it, I got following error: Subset out of range: `r[5]`

`Nsubj` is 5, and I want an r value per subject, however, I also want a value per data point as the magnitude of the difference between timecourse 1 and timecourse 2 can change throughout the movement set. I've been trying to solve this hours and I think I'm just missing something but I can't figure out the problem.

I hope someone can help me here!

Comment: Trying to troubleshoot a similar error message. This looks like it could be helpful Q and A: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27968882/8400969

Comment: Did you simply need it to be `r[j]~debeta(1,1)` so that you drew an r value per subject? This seems to fit your description for y[s[i],t] and also the fact that you included r inside the loop for `Nsubj`.